# UnitTest transformResponse function inside $resource - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

This is my service

```
 return $resource('/api/core/blablah', {}, {
  getTranslated: {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: true,
    transformResponse: function (data) {
      //do something here
      return 'something';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And i need to test my transformResponse function inside there.
This is my test:

```
  describe('blahblah', function describeFn() {
beforeEach(function beforeFn() {
  _httpBackend.whenGET('/api/core/blablah').respond(200, mockedPhones);

});

it('should call getTranslated', function stepFn() {
  var length = mockedPhones.phonesTypes.length;
  var res = phoneTypeSrv.getTranslated();
    expect(res).toBeDefined();
    expect(res.length).toEqual(length - 2);
  });

});
```

i have also tried like this

```
 it('should call getTranslated', function stepFn() {
  var length = mockedPhones.phonesTypes.length;
  phoneTypeSrv.getTranslated().$promise.then(function onThen(res) {
    expect(res).toBeDefined();
    expect(res.length).toEqual(length - 2);
  });
  _httpBackend.flush()
```

What would be the way to test that transformResponse function? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?